# Do we want accepted answers to be pinned to the top?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

#### Stack Exchange staff have announced [an upcoming change to the way answer acceptance works](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369568/unpinning-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top-of-the-list-of-answers).

Currently, the original poster of a question can *accept* one non-deleted answer. This does several things,

- the question poster receives 2 rep, and the answer poster receives 15 rep
- the answer has an added green tick mark below its score and vote buttons
- the answer itself is pinned to the top of the list of answers, regardless of sort variable

This change will affect the last of these behaviours, removing the "pin to top". Staff have indicated this may be configurable per site - each individual site can have this behaviour turned off or left on (with the default setting yet to be determined by consensus and research).

#### Please indicate by voting on the answers below, which setting you would prefer.

Downvotes will be ignored for this purpose, as they add no useful information. Just upvote one, or both or neither.

Feedback will be collated on September 19th, giving six days to make a decision.

Comment: This question and its answers were derived from the template created by Nij on [Sports SE](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1027), via [Astronomy SE](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/803/34513).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, the result (unpin) has been posted on Meta: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369914

Comment: The behavior has been implemented.

Comment: Perhaps now that SE decided to stick with the status quo, we should do another vote, where people now know that the vote is about whether or not to opt-in to what may become the site behavior on the minority of sites.

Comment: @user1271772 The behavior that most users voted for has been implemented, so I don't really see the need for another vote?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Remove the "pin to top" behaviour.

I want this behaviour to be removed. An accepted answer should be sorted in the same way as all answers.

Comment: I cannot vote but I would choose this one.

Comment: I vote for this option because sometimes the accepted answer is not always the best answer. On other occasions a better answer is posted after an answer has been accepted.

Comment: yes, I'm for this

Comment: I am for this too

Answer (score 1):

#### Keep the "pin to top" behaviour.

I want this behaviour to be kept. An accepted answer should be placed at the top of the list.